Probability ,"at least one and only on one "
I am doing a probability question where I have,
the probability of rain on November $23$ is  $0.4$, and the probability of rain on November $24$, is $0.3$.
Additionally, the probability of rain on only one of these dates is $0.16$.
What is the probability that it will rain on at least one of these dates?
what I did was P(A)=$0.4$,P(B)=$0.3$ , P(A xor B) =$0.16$
I wrote what I thought  at least one means as follows, it raining only on the first day or only on the second day or on both days
so
I did P(A and not B) or P(B and not A ) or P(B and A)  $0.4 *0.7 +0.6*0.3+0.4*0.3  $yet then I am not using the probability they gave for on only one of those days .
what does the  P(A xor B) =0.16 provide ?

You can not assume the events are independent.

in our uni we started learning the course by just diving in and solving problems we are not learning anything about the theories  so I do not really have a background on this topic can you elaborate a bit on dependence and independence , do you mean by  independent events what I did getting rid of the third info given and assuming that b not happening is 0.7 and so on?

You incorrectly assumed that the events were independent.  That is, you assumed things like $P(A\cap B)=P(A)\times P(B)$.  Just thinking about the real world, obviously knowing the weather today changes my view of the likely weather tomorrow.

what does $B^c$ means

If you want to work from scratch, I suggest:  There are $4$ possible events over the two days.  Let $P(A\cap B^c)=x$, $P(A^c\cap B)=y$, $P(A\cap B)=z$.  Then $P(A^c\cap B^c)=1-x-y-z$ (why?).  Use the given data to solve for $x,y,z$.

$B^c$ means "not $B$".  Standard notation for the complementary event.  In any case, I edited the comment to take that out (though I also used the notation in my second comment).

thank you very much  ,I will go and try to apply what I have learnt

If the probabilities are
                rain Nov 24   no rain Nov 24
   rain Nov 23       p             q
no rain Nov 23       r             s

then you have been told $p+q=0.4$ for November 23, and $p+r=0.3$ for November 24, and $q+r=0.16$ for "only one of these dates".
Since $p+q+r+s=1$, you have four linear equations in four unknowns which you can solve.  For example, $s=1-\frac{0.4+0.3+0.16}{2}$ and you need the $0.16$ to solve this.
You get the following results, which is easy to check with the original information.  Rain on the two days are clearly not independent.
                rain Nov 24   no rain Nov 24
   rain Nov 23      0.27           0.13
no rain Nov 23      0.03           0.57

That gives $p+q+r=0.43$ to answer the question of the probability of rain on at least one day.  A quicker way here is to note that $p+q+r=\frac{(p+q)+(p+r)+(q+r)}{2}$ though this may be slightly harder to check.

is p the probability of rain on nov 24 and nov 23 where as q is no rain on nov 24 yet raining on nov 23 ?

I think my problem is deducing the translation of such probabilities into p+q and p+r

@dareen Yes - and $r$ is the probability of rain on Nov 24 but not Nov 23, and $s$ of no rain on either day.  So the probability of rain on November 23 of $0.4$ is the sum of probabilities in the Nov 23 row, i.e. $p+q$.

oh I see thanks ,I will read all the answers and then accept one but I am certainly benefiting from all of you

The point is that $$P(A\text{ xor }B)=(P(A)-P(A\cap B))+(P(B)-P(A\cap B))\\=P(A)+P(B)-2P(A\cap B).$$ So from the given information you can work out $P(A\cap B)$ and use it to find $P(A\cup B)$.
What you have done (assuming independence) cannot be right because it would give $$P(A\text{ and not }B)+P(B\text{ and not }A)\overset{?}{=}0.28+0.18=0.46,$$ but you know the actual value is $0.16$.

yeah this actually why I even posted this I got 0.46 and they gave 0.16 so i assumed I have a fundamental problem in understanding the given input

Two facts to use:

The event of $A$ exclusive or that of $B$, is the set difference $A\operatorname\Delta B$ which is $(A\cup B)\smallsetminus(A\cap B)$.

$A\cup B = A\cup(B\smallsetminus(A\cap B))$ where the RHS is a union of disjoint events.


Thus you have two simultaneous equations with two unknowns :
$$\begin{align}\Bbb P(A\operatorname\Delta B) &= \Bbb P(A\cup B)-\Bbb P(A\cap B)\tag 1\\[2ex]\Bbb P(A\cup B)&=\Bbb P(A)+\Bbb P(B)-\Bbb P(A\cap B)\tag 2\end{align}$$

